# Makemigrations and auto_now_add

Tags: django-models

**Django 1.9.7**

**PostgreSQL**

Could you help me understand what should I do? 
The option auto_now_addand default are mutually exclusive.

This is just a bit confusing. I'm in favour of pressing 1? But just decided to ask for some piece of advice.

**Model**

```
creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Traceback**

```
michael@michael:~/workspace/photoarchive$ python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'creation_date' to place without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

Comment: choose 1 and set `datetime.datetime.now()` as default

Comment: There was a piece of advice here. Add null=True, makemigrations, remove null=True. Well, it helped. But null=True seems to be harmless here. Maybe there is no need to remove null=True?

Comment: sorry - did change the comment - as maybe `null=Ture` is not the best idea.

Comment: Why? The table is empty so far. there will be nothing there. And in production auto_now_add will just do the job.

Comment: Ok - if you don't have any entries yet it does not matter. With existing entries it would be better to use a default value that is set to a valid date.  
And finally the `creation_date` should likely never be `NULL` - just to keep thing clean and be prepared if your database is migrated to another framework/whatever in 5 years :)

Comment: Well, it does matter: I run  makemigrations a lot of times. It really saves me a lot of typing. Well, if you organize it as an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Similar issue on Django 2.2.
No meaningful solution seems OK